# LINQ query to get All objects information from given database in ASP.NET?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a requirement that,
I populate all database in one DropDownList and when i changed the database name.
I need to display all objects present in the database into a gridview.
I need to do it in LINQ to SQl
could any one please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks and Regards,
G. Kiran

Answer (score 0):

I found this code somewhere

```
Northwind db = ...from somewhere
var model = db.Mapping;
foreach (var mt in model.GetTables())
   Console.WriteLine(mt.TableName);
```